# programmatically yahoo mail navigation

Tags: navigation, email, yahoo

I want to write a program which can save latest 10 mails from my yahoo email account as text
files given yahoo username and pwd.

I tried using python
ie = Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")

I was able to sign-in but could not use
ie.document.getElementsByName(" ")
ie.document.getElementsById(" ")
to read emails

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a basic Yahoo account via IMAP
by issuing a non-standard ID ("GUID" "1") command.
The following code illustrates this by printing out the message ids of all your new emails:

```
require 'net/imap'
Net::IMAP.debug = true
conn = Net::IMAP.new('imap.mail.yahoo.com', 143, false)
conn.instance_eval { send_command('ID ("GUID" "1")') }
conn.authenticate('LOGIN', ARGV[0], ARGV[1] )
conn.select("INBOX")
uids = conn.uid_search(['NEW'])
puts uids.join(',')
conn.logout
conn.disconnect
```

Be aware that there is a bug in ruby net/imap library.
You need to apply the patch referenced here:

[Connecting to Yahoo! mail from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254229/connecting-to-yahoo-mail-from-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to do this with POP3/IMAP? Just fetch the last 10 mails and leave the on the server?

This way you are not dependent on the Yahoo website. (if it changes your code will break since its dependent on the UI).

Comment: only yahoo mail plus gives access to pop3/imap.
I am using a yahoo mail basic account.